# how to add yahoo account to claws mail 

Tags: 12.04, yahoo, claws

I've seen a post that claws mail is very light . so I've downloaded that and installed in my ubuntu 12.04 . but while trying to add my yahoo account its doesn't behaving like thunderbird client . so all I need to configure manually and I did it but I'm not getting any mails download from yahoo server . I'm not getting the issue .

thanks for any advice .

Answer (score 1):

"How can I use my free Hotmail, Yahoo, or AOL email account via Claws Mail?
FreePOPs should allow you to create kind of a "bridge" between these proprietary email services and Claws Mail. Simply install FreePOPs, which is probably packaged in your distribution and configure it. After that, you can add an POP3 account to Claws Mail, which receiving server will be localhost and set the port to use to 2000 in the Advanced tab. The username to use consists of a complete email address, like johndoe@hotmail.com, so that FreePOP can know which type of account it is. For more information, see FreePOPs' user manual."

http://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Installation_and_Configuration#How_can_I_use_my_free_Hotmail.2C_Yahoo.2C_or_AOL_email_account_via_Claws_Mail.3F